# Problems joining pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

So i'm trying to join two dataframes together to plot against another dataframe.

I tried:

```
genders2 = np.array(male_grades[['grade_difs']].join(female_grades[['grade_difs']], how='outer'))
```

and get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'
```

I was able to use this type of code earlier in the program i'm writing:

```
genders = np.array(male[['MaleAge']].join(female[['FemaleAge']], how='outer'))
```

If i'm being too vague let me know and ill try to add more code to make it more sense or something.

Code before:

```
data['grade_difs'] = (data['OGrade'] - data['IGrade'])

female_grades = data[data['Gender'] == 'F']['grade_difs']
male_grades = data[data['Gender'] == 'M']['grade_difs']
```

Comment: The error indicates that `male` is a `pd.Series` and when you slice it with `male[['MaleAge']]` you get another `pd.Series`... and `pd.Series` does not have a `join` method.  You want to check your other code and see how `male` became a `pd.Series` if yo didn't intend it to be.

Comment: the male_grades? I just edited it to show the code right before it.

Comment: Maybe pd.concat will help you in you case.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 1):

Two points

1. You are definitely getting a `pd.Series` in `male_grades`.  This will fix it

   ```
   female_grades = data[data['Gender'] == 'F'][['grade_difs']]
   male_grades = data[data['Gender'] == 'M'][['grade_difs']]
   ```
2. But I'd rather do it like this

   ```
   female_grades = data.loc[data['Gender'] == 'F', ['grade_difs']]
   male_grades = data.loc[data['Gender'] == 'M', ['grade_difs']]
   ```

---

After that, you need to make sure you specify suffixes in your `join` in case you have column names in common.  It's often sufficient to specify suffixes on one side of the join.

```
male[['MaleAge']].join(female[['FemaleAge']], how='outer', rsuffix='_')
```

Comment: Thank you, however; i'm not getting error: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['grade_difs'], dtype='object')            Does this mean the index of the data frames dont line up?

Comment: So you've gotten past the first error and on to another error.  That's good.  That's progress :-)  This one is because you have column names in common.  Its difficult to do this when you don't provide a complete example.  You should always provide what we call a minimal and complete verifiable example or [***MCVE***](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @ksalerno, please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43499776/edit) your post accordingly

Comment: well the two columns that i'm joining are both called 'grade_difs', so that is the problem no? is is it stemming from something else

Comment: @ksalerno you need to formulate your question better.  Go back and think about your problem.  Put together an complete example that demonstrates your problem.  Then edit this question or ask a new one that is clear and asks a specific question.